# Replacing AWS ELB in K8 cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubectl

I have a k8 cluster deployed in AWS using kube-aws. When I deploy a service, a new ELB is added for exposing the service to internet. Can I use ingress-controller to replace ELB or is there any other way to expose services other than ELB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, replace  `type: LoadBalancer` with `type: ClusterIP` in your service definition. Then you have to configure the [ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/ingress/) and deploy a controller, like [Nginx](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/tree/master/ingress/controllers/nginx)

If you are looking for a full example, I have one here: [nginx-ingress-controller](https://github.com/camilb/prometheus-kubernetes/tree/master/definitions/k8s/ingress).

The ingress will expose you services using some of your workers public IPs, usually 2 of them. Just check your ingress `kubectl get ing -o wide` and create the DNS records.